# indexing a collection

Tags: c#

I have an with several properties:

```
MyModel{
public int var1 {get;set;}
public int var2 {get;set;}
public int TheIndex {get;set;}
}
```

I use this model to populate a list:

```
var Output = .... select new MyModel {... TheIndex = 0, ...};
```

Then, I want to fill the index of each element with:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var a in Output) { a.TheIndex = index++; }
```

However, I'm baffled to figure out why it's not adding the index like I think it should. Instead, it's stuck at 0 across the entire collection.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `MyModel` a `struct` or `class`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is adding the index. The issue is that you are mutating objects streamed out by a *query*. I'm guessing that you are subsequently re-executing the query and expecting those mutations to have somehow been 'persisted' into the query in a manner that will be reflected in the *new* results of the query. LINQ queries don't work that way : the result of a query expression is a *query*, not the results of the query. Every time you enumerate the results, the query runs again. In your case, *new* instances of `MyModel` will be created again, so the changes performed on the old ones are lost.

A few possible fixes:

1. Build the appropriate index for each element into the query itself.
2. Materialize the query into a collection (e.g. with a `ToList()` call), and then mutate the elements of the collection.
3. Perform the 'final' necessary side-effect (which you haven't shown us) on each element of the result-sequence *inside* the `foreach` loop rather than by re-executing the query after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "not adding the index like I think it should" however I'd point out that there is a Select extension method that would do what you want in one operation. So

```
var Output = .... select new MyModel { ... TheIndex = 0, ...};
```

would become

```
var Output = (....).Select((elem, idx) => new MyModel { ... TheIndex = idx, ... });
```